# Injecting css link in Vue CLI build output

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

So this is a project in Laravel with Vue+Vuetify frontend. I'm using Vue CLI. I have set Vue CLI's output directory to Laravel's public folder using `vue.config.js`, like this:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
      devtool: 'source-map'
    },
    devServer: {
      proxy: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/',
  },
  outputDir: '../public',

  indexPath: '../resources/views/index.blade.php',
}
```

This works. However mdi icons on the web page do not show. I understand that I need to add link tag `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/.../materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` to the index file, but I don't know where do I add it. The `index.blade.php` is overwritten by the Build process every time.

Alternate path is to include that css file in the build process by installing npm package and adding a few lines to my `main.js`, but I'd rather avoid that since my output is already getting bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out soon after posting question. I'll post it here for my own record and for anyone else landing here.

The solution was simpler than I anticipated. Vue CLI uses contents of `/public` folder to generate build output. So the solution was to simply go to `public/index.html` and place the meta tag in there.

Note: In my case I created a Laravel project and then used Vue CLI to create a Vue project inside Laravel project folder, so my folder structure looked like this:

```
Laravel_Project
--app
--bootstrap
--...
--public
--Vue_CLI_Project
----src
----public
```

Note that there are two `public` folders: First one is in Laravel project's root directory, whereas the second one is inside Vue project's directory. We are talking about the second one here.